# how to transform domain.com/news.php?post_id=56 into domain.com/news/post-56

Tags: php, url

How to rewrite URL bar like so:

> http://domain.com/news.php?post_id=56

into

> http://domain.com/news/post-56?

Answer (score 0):

It need to be done in .htaccess file
There is such thing as RewriteEngine
and code can look something like that

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^news/([^/]+)/?$    news.php?post_id=$1 [NC,L]
```

in begining we turn on rewrite engine
first two conditions check if there is no such file or folder - in your case news
then we rewrite what is typed in to what we need in our system

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by URL rewriting.

**URL rewriting** is asking server to call specific file/script on certain **URL** requests.

Depending on the software your server is running, you may already have access to URL rewriting modules. If not, most hosts will enable or install the relevant modules for you if you ask them very nicely.

Apache is the easiest system to get URL rewriting running on. It usually comes with its own built-in URL rewriting module, **mod_rewrite**, enabled, and working with mod_rewrite.

---

To do this,

You need to first create a text document called `.htaccess` to contain our rules. This would be placed in the root directory of the server. There may already be an .htaccess file there, in which case we should edit that rather than overwrite it.

Now your `.htaccess` file will look something like this,

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule    ^news/post-([0-9]+)/?$    news.php?post_id=$1    [NC,L]    # Handling post requests
```

---

**[NC,L]** - They are called **Flags**, that tell Apache how to apply the rule. In this case, we're using two flags. **NC**, tells Apache that this rule should be case-insensitive, and **L** tells Apache not to process any more rules if this one is used.

---

Above **RewriteRule** tell Apache to look for **news.php** file with `post-id` passed in **news/post-([0-9]+)/** URL. Where **[0-9]** denotes any numeric vaue.

Learn more here: https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/